# send mail form - get value from radio button

Tags: php, forms, radio-button, mailing

I have already tried many solutions I found on this site but I can't seem to figure this out.

My radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="apartman" />
<label for="radio1">Apartman 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="apartman" />
<label for="radio2">Sunny Shit 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="apartman" />
<label for="radio3">Penthouse</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio4" name="apartman" />
<label for="radio4">Rupčaga</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio5" name="apartman" />
<label for="radio5">Štala Gold Class</label>
```

And this is the PHP I got in mailing script:

```
$apartman = $_POST['apartman'];
```

The result I keep geting in my mail is:

Apartman: on

Result I want to get:

Apartman: [value of selected radio button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that differenciates each of your radio buttons is the `id` attribute, however the ID is not used in calculating the form data, you also need to add a `value` attribute to each of your radio buttons, and you will get the desired effect:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="apartman" value="radio1" />
<label for="radio1">Apartman 1</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="apartman" value="radio2" />
<label for="radio2">Sunny Shit 2</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio3" name="apartman" value="radio3" />
<label for="radio3">Penthouse</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio4" name="apartman" value="radio4" />
<label for="radio4">Rupčaga</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio5" name="apartman" value="radio5" />
<label for="radio5">Štala Gold Class</label>
```